# Puppeteer Change CSS to all Selectors

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Now Puppeteer change only an first element, but I need to change at all selectors.

```
let textContent = await page.$('td[style="visibility:hidden"]');
await textContent.evaluate((el) => el.style.visibility = 'visible');
```

this work only on first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`page.$$`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) instead

```
let elements = await page.$$('td[style="visibility:hidden"]');
for(const element of elements) {
  await element.evaluate((el) => el.style.visibility = 'visible');
}
```